# Remove Lines with more than X number of letters Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

How do I remove lines with more than X number of letters/numbers?

I see the options to replace words, but that's about it. I've done some Google searches and I have not been able to find this question answered.

Comment: Example please.

Comment: As in before and after examples perhaps!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do that in one pass, so here's two steps:

First, You can find lines having length above 4 character with Regular Expressions and replace them with anything you want, eg three ###. You could of course replace with empty line, but if you had empty lines that you want to preserve, I think any string that's unlikely to happen in your text file will do. I choose ###.

[image: Replace step 1]

Then find Extended like this and replace with nothing (empty field) like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer from @nhahtdh here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614591/remove-long-lines-from-text-file-notepad-editplus

They provide examples for Notepad++ which I just tested and seem to work for me in current Notepad++

Same questions, different network site, so not strictly speaking a duplicate.